# Definition of differentiability at the point in multivariable calculus.

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, definition

I'm self-studying the analysis from Zorich and the next definition of differentiability is given:
$f:E\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable at the point $x$, which is a limit point of $E\subset \mathbb{R}^m$, if 
$f(x+h)-f(x)=L(x)\cdot h+\alpha(x;h)$, so that  $L(x):\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is linear map wrt $h$ and $\dfrac{\alpha(x;h)}h\to 0$ while $h\to 0$ for $x+h \in E$.

Why do we need the linearity of $L$ wrt $h$? What do we lose if $L$ is not linear? Why $x$ is the argument of $L$, isn't it fixed? Shouldn't it be $L(h):\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why do we need the linearity of $L$ wrt $h$? What do we lose if $L$ is not linear?**

The derivation at a point shall be the best *linear* approximation of the function at this point. More precisely $L$ is the best *linear* approximation of the difference function $g(h):=f(x+h)-f(x)$ for a fixed point $x$.

**Why $x$ is the argument of $L$, isn't it fixed? Shouldn't it be $L(h):\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n$?**

For each point $x$ you will get a different linear map $L(x):\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n$. Note that $L(x)$ is a matrix / linear map not a vector. This linear map, which is the best linear approximation of the function at this point, depends only on the function $f$ and the point $x$.

Because $L(x)$ is a map, $L(x)\cdot h = L(x)(h)$ is the approximation of the difference $f(x+h)-f(x)$. -> $L(x)(h)$ is a vector.

Comment: Ok. So wouldn't it be better to right $L_x(h)$ instead of $L(x)(h)$. Because it feels like $L(x_1+c\cdot x_2)=L(x_1)+c\cdot L(x_2)$ which is wrong, since $L(x)$ is a matrix, and there is no reason why derivative at point $x_1+x_2$ should  depend on derivatives at the points $x_1$ and $x_2$. Although on the other hand $L$ is also a function wrt $x$ which has $\mathbb{R}^m$ as its domain and set of matrices $m$ by  $n$ as its codomain. Right?

Comment: @Mihail: Good point and you are right in what you said... $L_x$ or $L_x(h)$ seems to me to be a better notation but that's a question of taste for the author...